# TreePanel Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined

Tags: extjs, treepanel

I've a problem while rendering TreePanel. I'm using MVC structure, here's my definition: 
*(By the way I don't use dynamic loading, included ext-all-debug.)*

**Menu - Model**

```
Ext.define('RIA4.model.Menu', {    extend        : 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty    : 'menuId',
fields        : [
    { name : 'menuId',         type : 'int' },
    { name : 'menuName',    type : 'string' },
    { name : 'sourcePath',     type : 'string' },
    { name : 'active',         type : 'boolean', defaultValue : true },
    { name : 'leaf',         type : 'boolean' }
]
```

});

**TreeStore**

```
Ext.define('RIA4.store.Menus', {    extend        : 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
model        : 'RIA4.model.Menu',
proxy        : {
    type    : 'ajax',
    api        : {
        read    : 'menu/view.ajax'
    },
    reader    : {
        type    : 'json',
        root    : 'data',
        successProperty : 'success'
    }
},
autoLoad    : true
```

});

**TreePanel**

```
Ext.define('RIA4.view.menu.MenuTree', {    extend        : 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias        : 'widget.menutree',
//requires    : [],
title        : 'Menu List',
store        : 'Menus',
rootVisible    : false,
root        : {expanded: true, text: "", "data": []}
```

});

I'll be happy if someone can help me?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't you forgotten to add the following line to controller's config:

```
   views: [ 'menu.MenuTree' ],
```

Comment: forgot to add the component to the controller. Even you don't need to control the component, you should add it to view config of controller, interesting point.. thanks Molecule Man..